# Programmatically change settings

Tags: google-chrome, browser, console, chromium

With Firefox, you can change browser settings with the *Browser Console*:

```js
Services.prefs.setInfPref('browser.startup.page', 3);
```

Note that this does not work with the *Web Console*:

```
> Services
ReferenceError: Services is not defined [Learn More]
```

Does Chrome/Chromium have a similar way to programmatically set preferences?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use Ubuntu GNU/Linux, and Chromium as my primary browser, and never tried Chrome in Linux. So, for Chromium in Linux I have an answer and I think It should be same for Chrome too. Apparently you can [refer this link](https://superuser.com/questions/554233/how-to-change-preferences-in-chrome-by-modifying-files) for Windows Platform.

So, Default Preferences for Chromium Browser in Linux are saved in ([See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7ow3.jpg))

> /home/$USER/.config/chromium/Default/

It is much similar to `prefs.js` file `for customizing Default Preferences in Mozilla Firefox` but don't know whether It's a `.js` file or not.

Anyways the `Preferences` file looks [like this](https://pastebin.com/WFHAY80Z). It looks a kind of messy, So, I thought to indent it to make some sense. To view Formmated
file [Click here](https://pastebin.com/VwVTfWJ1). It stores the each preference in the comma separated values where each preference is written in form of JSON Markup

> " Preference name " : " value "

Apart from this, in the same folder, there is also a file named "Secure Preferences" that stores only one preference.

As far as programming the preferences are concerned, [Chromium Project Page](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-other-preferences) specifies the differences between the Ploicies & Preferences, and also suggests to write ploicies instead of preferences beacuse Policies take precedence to preferences.  If "homepage" is specified in both the policies, and in the "master_preferences" file, policies will always override.

You can edit Preferences for the Browser as stated in these pages :

[The Chromium Project Page :: Configuring Other Preferences](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-other-preferences) : 
Under the Section Preferences vs. Policies - 3rd bullet point under Preferences.

[The Chromium Project Page :: Preferences](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/preferences) : Under the Section Introduction - 6th line. Also this particular page explains pretty much everything you need to do to set preferences programmatically. I am sure that will work for you.

For just a little Reference, See [this post by sputnam](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/10331/chrome-master-preferences-file-and-suppressing-first-run-browser), in which he shows a sample of Preferences Code edited by him.

Comment: @StevenPenny Updated my answer to address your Comment.Also, Chromium Project Page states nothing about `Secure Preferences`. Maybe we don't need that one to edit. I think editing the `Preferences` file would do.

Comment: you comment is not valid because the important `restore_on_startup` setting is stored in "Secure Preferences", and your edit is not valid because current Chromium wont read any secure preferences from `master_preferences` file, if any at all

Comment: Thanks for pointing it, I should do some more research.

Comment: If Chrome is running while you edit this file, then I think it will be overwritten